# Save Raster Layer As... not working in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, raster-conversion

I am trying to save a VRT layer as a TIFF file using the layers panel in QGIS 3.4.

I successfully created and saved the VRT from multiple ASC LiDAR tiles. My method is to work from the layers panel, right-click the VRT layer and select Export/Save As. The Save Raster Layer As... window opens, but whatever I enter -- raw data or rendered image, or any other options -- nothing happens and no file is created.

There are no error messages. The Cancel button does not work: the window stays open. I can close the window using the Close Window 'x' in the bar.

I can convert the VRT to a TIF if I use Raster/Conversion/Translate but that is not so intuitive, and the option appears to be there in the layers window.

QGIS 3.4.9 LTR, Linux Xubuntu 18.04 LTR, 64-bit

Comment: that sounds like a bug

Comment: I have just come across this same issue? Is there a fix for it at present?